# How to call method to populate form controls in the main file if the method is in another class file?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So in my main for I do some work with files and after processing them I save some values in variables.

In my showResults class file I have the Results method which looks something like this:

```
class ShowResults : Main
{
    public void Results(string item, int counterL, int counterS, int counterB, long tick, int miss)
    {
        if (item == "Fbubble")
        {
            loadBubble.Text = counterL.ToString();
            storeBubble.Text = counterS.ToString();
            branchBubble.Text = counterB.ToString();
            ticksBubble.Text = tick.ToString();
            icMissInstrBubble.Text = miss.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

How do I call this in my main form class so it will populate the necessary fields?

Comment: what you are trying to do is something you should not do... you should let your form class handle the display of those values and only return the values to the form

Comment: Why you want call method from main class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why you would want to do it this way, but if you must, I suggest making it static:

```
public static class ShowResults : Main
{
    public static void Results(string item, int counterL, int counterS, int counterB, long tick, int miss)
    {
        if (item == "Fbubble")
        {
            loadBubble.Text = counterL.ToString();
            storeBubble.Text = counterS.ToString();
            branchBubble.Text = counterB.ToString();
            ticksBubble.Text = tick.ToString();
            icMissInstrBubble.Text = miss.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage could be something like this:

```
button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowResults.Results(<String>, <Int32>, <Int32>, <Int32>, <long>, <Int32>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's better that you create a controller class for processing values and get result from controller class and display the result with view class. you can use model-view-controller design pattern. For more information use this link:  [Model-view-Controller Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Answer (score 0):

a full source example how you could do that without making your form static...

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form,ISomeCallbackInterface
    {
        #region designer stuff
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.textBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.textBox3 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(65, 49);
            this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
            this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.textBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // textBox2
            // 
            this.textBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(65, 75);
            this.textBox2.Name = "textBox2";
            this.textBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.textBox2.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // textBox3
            // 
            this.textBox3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(65, 101);
            this.textBox3.Name = "textBox3";
            this.textBox3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.textBox3.TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(65, 173);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 3;
            this.button1.Text = "do something";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(65, 202);
            this.button2.Name = "button2";
            this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 35);
            this.button2.TabIndex = 4;
            this.button2.Text = "do something with a callback";
            this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox3);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox3;
        private Button button2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;

        #endregion

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var x = SomeOtherClassDoingStuff.DoSomethingThatReturns();
            HandleSomeReturnValue(x);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SomeOtherClassDoingStuff.DoSomethingByCallbackInterface(this);
        }

        void ISomeCallbackInterface.TheActualCallback(SomeRetrunValueClass theValueReturnedToTheCallback)
        {
            HandleSomeReturnValue(theValueReturnedToTheCallback);
        }

        private void HandleSomeReturnValue(SomeRetrunValueClass theValue)
        {
            textBox1.Text = theValue.A.ToString();
            textBox2.Text = theValue.B.ToString();
            textBox3.Text = theValue.C;
        }


    }

    public interface ISomeCallbackInterface
    {
        void TheActualCallback(SomeRetrunValueClass theValueReturnedToTheCallback);
    }

    public class SomeOtherClassDoingStuff
    {
        public static SomeRetrunValueClass DoSomethingThatReturns()
        {
            return new SomeRetrunValueClass { A = 123, B = 0.456, C = "Something" };
        }

        public static void DoSomethingByCallbackInterface(ISomeCallbackInterface Callback) 
        {
            Callback.TheActualCallback(new SomeRetrunValueClass { A = 234, B = 0.567, C = "Something else" });
        }
    }

    public class SomeRetrunValueClass
    {
        public int A { get; set; }
        public double B { get; set; }
        public String C { get; set; }
    }

}
```